# Page 23 is empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, challenges

I'm sorry for nitpicking, but when navigating to 'Questions' one can browse up to page 23. However, page 23 is plainly empty:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?page=23&sort=newest

Is this a bug by any chance?

(Perhaps this problem disappears when a question is posted, but at the moment this can be experienced)

Comment: Empty for me too. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Sounds like an off-by-one. The site currently has 330 questions, which is wholly divisible by 15 (the page size). I suspect that this recurs every 15/30/50 posts (depending on which paging setting you use).

Comment: Another possibility is that the paginator is working with a total number of questions, but the displayed ones are being filtered so only fill 22 pages. ie there could be questions that have been hidden somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a rounding error here resulting in an off-by-one on the last page once that rounding went up, this is fixed in the next build.